# PostgreSQL problem with a updating request between two tables

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update in Postgres (with pgadmin4, version 5.5) a table with a classical join request and it doesn't work.
See the code:

I want to update column `labcommune` from table bof.col
with column lib_com from table bof.libcom

When i perform a simple crossing request:

```
select c.insee c_insee, c.lab_commune, l.insee l_insee, l.lib_com
from bof.col as c
join bof.libcom as l
on c.insee=l.insee
```

no problem, the return is:

| c_insee | lab_commune | l_insee | lib_com |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01343 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon | 01343 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon |
| 01346 | Saint-Didier-d'Aussiat | 01346 | Saint-Didier-d'Aussiat |
| 01348 | Saint-Didier-sur-Chalaronne | 01348 | Saint-Didier-sur-Chalaronne |
| 01349 | Saint-�loi | 01349 | Saint-Éloi |
| 01350 | Saint-�tienne-du-Bois | 01350 | Saint-Étienne-du-Bois |

->Each item of  bof.col crosses the right item of lib_com

but when U try an UPDATE statement:

```
 update bof.col
   set lab_commune=l.lib_com
   from bof.col as c
   join bof.libcom as l
   on c.insee=l.insee
```

I have this return  in bof.col

| insee | lab_commune |
| --- | --- |
| 01343 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon |
| 01346 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon |
| 01348 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon |
| 01349 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon |
| 01350 | Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon |

->Item 'Saint-Cyr-sur-Menthon' is duplicate over all rows.
What's the matter I don't see?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the `UPDATE` statement is different than the syntax for the `SELECT` statement.
The updated table should not be referenced again in the `FROM` clause and instead of the `ON` clause use a `WHERE` clause.
This is how you do an implicit join with the `UPDATE` statement in Postgresql:

```
update bof.col as c
set lab_commune = l.lib_com
from bof.libcom as l
where c.insee = l.insee;
```

Comment: Of course, you're right! Sometimes we need a good night's sleeps! Thank you for you reply.

Comment: @FredGina fine if it helped and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.